# Nifi Processor to performantly handle asynchronous tasks

Tags: asynchronous, apache-nifi

I have a Nifi processor that is calling an external service that can take days before a result is returned.  During this time the processor can call Thread.sleep() periodically to relinquish CPU.

The issue is that even if Thread.sleep() is called in an onTrigger() method, the NiFi processor will not read in and handle new FlowFiles since it is waiting for onTrigger() to finish.  From NiFi's perspective the cpu is still blocking for the asynchronous call to finish.

Is there a way to maintain concurrency when asynchronous calls are being made in the onTrigger() method of a NiFi processor?

Comment: Hi @AlexEthier. Is it a custom Processor or something like a InvokeHTTP processor ? Do you know why the external service is slow: is it because it takes days to process and respond, or because of another reason (service unavailable...) ? -> Does it make sense to put the flowFile in a waiting queue and try again later instead of keeping it "in" in the Processor? Does it make sense to increase the "Concurrent Tasks" of the Processor?

Comment: This is a custom processor.  My NiFi flow is pulling data to a central location where model training is run.  Training a model can take a few days.  I don't want to increase the "Concurrent Tasks" because this will take away cpu from other parts of NiFi.  I think after initiating the asynchronous request, routing the flowfiles back out to a 'waiting' queue will work.  A reference to the asynchronous request will be held in memory and once complete, the matching flowfile in the waiting queue will be pulled back in and output to the success relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Val Bonn's suggestion of pushing asynchronous FlowFiles back to a WAIT queue works well.  As asynchronous requests come in, java Process objects are created and held in memory.  The FlowFile is then routed to a WAIT relationship which is connected back into the processor.  Periodically FlowFiles from the WAIT queue are checked against the corresponding Process to see if it completed and are then routed to a SUCCESS relationship, otherwise they are penalized.  This allows many long running asynchronous processes to be kicked off without allocating precious cpu resources for each incoming request.  One source of complexity was handling processor shutdowns invoked from the UI.  In these situations an onStopped method is invoked that waits for all in memory processes to complete and archives the stderr and stdout to disk.  When the processor is started again, the archive is read back in and paired against any FlowFiles in the WAIT queue.